# How Yolo 3 is implemented in Yolo 4?

Tags: deep-learning, architecture, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I try to understand the architecture of Yolo4.
It is composed of a backbone, neck, dense prediction and sparse prediction.
Knowing that Yolo 3 has already a backbone, Is Yolo 4 taking all the architecture of Yolo 3 including its backbone or just part of Yolo3 ?

In page number 5 in paper Yolo 4, they've mentioned anchor based for Yolo3

Yolo 4 : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10934.pdf

Yolo 3 :https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yolov4 Vs Yolov3:**

- Yolov3 uses **`Darknet53`** as backbone, Yolov4 uses
  **`CSPDarknet53`** as backbone.
- Yolov4 uses `PANet` as the method of parameter aggregation from different backbone levels for different detector levels, instead of the `FPN` used in Yolov3.

YOLOv4 consists of:

1. **Backbone:** CSPDarknet53  (Feature Extraction)
2. **Neck:** Additional module - SPP, PANet [this was not there in Yolov3]
3. **Head:** YOLOv3 (Dense Prediction Block) [This part is same as Yolov3]

[image: Yolov4-arch]

> **Neck:** Object detectors developed in recent years often insert some
> layers between backbone and head, and these layers are usually used to
> collect feature maps from different stages.

References:

- Read [Yolov4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10934.pdf) paper in detail
- Read [this](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/yolov4-c9901eaa8e61) article

Comment: @MathieuConze If my answer has addressed and answered your question, please upvote it and `mark answer as accepted`, so that it will help other SO users.